# Every-time receiving ACTION_DOWN even though I tried to move image up side

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, motionevent, android-touch-event

I have a custom `BottomSheetDialogFragment` which contains drag icon to move sheet up/down.
But I am facing weired issue with touch listener. Everytime it receives `ACTION_DOWN` event even though I simply click on it or try to push it up.

Below is the code

```
binding.dragDownImage.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
            when(motionEvent.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    //if (motionEvent.y < 12)
                        dismiss()
                }
                else -> { }
            }
            true
        }
```

I want to dismiss bottom sheet only when user drags it downwards otherwise it should expand.

Please help me here. Thanks

Comment: If you dismiss the dialog the moment you get the first ACTION_DOWN, how will it be possible to drag it?

Comment: Dismiss will happen only when ACTION_DOWN occurs otherwise it won't. Dismiss call is written inside same clause.

Comment: But the instant it is tapped, that’s the down action so it will be dismissed before there is an opportunity to drag it.

Comment: Okay any workaround for this?

Comment: Oh, I just realized that maybe you thought ACTION_DOWN means the view was dragged down a significant amount. Touch listeners and MotionEvents are much lowers level than that. They report every change in touch data. ACTION DOWN means a finger just contacted the screen. It will be followed by possible number of ACTION_MOVE events if the user drags the finger, and then either ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL.

Comment: For all these events it’s up to you to determine and track which finger you’re watching for, where it is, where it is relative to the point it touched down, and what to do while it moves (such as changing a view’s position by the change in Y compared to the touch down position to execute a drag) and what to do when the finger is released, based on where it is released. This is not a trivial task.